# Most efficient way to get all sub sites under a site collection/sub site using JSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

For the question lets assume the following site hierarchy

- Root Site

  - Sub Site 01

    - Sub Site 0101
    - Sub Site 0102

      - Sub Site 010201
  - Sub Site 02
  - Sub Site 03

    - Sub Site 0301

Now if I want to get all these sub site object in an array, what would be the best approach.

PS - ****rootWeb.get_webs()**** would return me just the immediate child sub sites. This would require me the make a recursive async call to each child sub site to get further down the hierarchy. I m guessing this will have performance issues and callback challenges.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### How to retrieve all web sites under a site collection using SharePoint JSOM

The following function demonstrates how to *recursively* retrieve all sub sites:

```
function getAllWebs(success,error)
{
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb();
   var result = [];
   var level = 0;
   var getAllWebsInner = function(web,result,success,error) 
   {
      level++;
      var ctx = web.get_context();
      var webs = web.get_webs(); 
      ctx.load(webs,'Include(Title,Webs)');
      ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < webs.get_count();i++){
                var web = webs.getItemAtIndex(i);
                result.push(web);
                if(web.get_webs().get_count() > 0) {
                   getAllWebsInner(web,result,success,error);
                }   
            }
            level--;
            if (level == 0 && success)
              success(result);  
        },
        error);
   };

   getAllWebsInner(web,result,success,error);    
}
```

[getAllWebs.js](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/3c7d735d3ed33d07b283)

**Usage**

```
getAllWebs(
function(allwebs){
    for(var i = 0; i < allwebs.length;i++){
        console.log(allwebs[i].get_title());   
    }
},
function(sendera,args){
    console.log(args.get_message());
});
```

Comment: Short of writing your own endpoint to expose the AllWebs property of the SPSite object, this recursion is the best/only way - so you should probably avoid it if your site is too nested and load the sub sites on demand

Comment: @Choggo I agree with your comment about the highly nested site hierarchy. This is my concern. I was wondering if there is any better way to get all sub site under a site (read as web). Just a thought, Will search api suit better?

Comment: The search API is a good idea (but has a limit of 500 items per page - might not be a problema). If you are on premise, you can write a REST service to return the information for you, as well.