# How to check Approve permission level for current user using Rest api for all the lists in Site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, jsom, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a site collection in share point online. Its has some lists and  sub sites. Again the sub sites having some lists. Some sub sites and lists having **unique** permissions and some have inheritance permissions . I need to check whether the  current login having  permission level  **Approve** for any lists  in all the sub sites and lists using rest api. Actually i am looking for a function(sample code) which iterate the sites collection lists and sub sites  lists for checking the **Approve** permission level for the lists.   i am using **/_api/site/rootWeb/webinfos** to get the sub sites ServerRelativeUrl .

Can anyone help me please.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a ready made sample for your but here is a good starting sample to iterate all subsite: [Most efficient way to get all sub sites under a site collection/sub site using JSOM?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130403/most-efficient-way-to-get-all-sub-sites-under-a-site-collection-sub-site-using-j?rq=1)

Try extending the script at after "var web = webs.getItemAtIndex(i);" to query the site for it's lists and include in the load whether the list HasUniquePermissions en the Roleassignments.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below sample code for get permission of current user in particular list.

```
function checkPermissions() {
    var call = jQuery.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
            "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Test')/effectiveBasePermissions",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });

call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var manageListsPerms = new SP.BasePermissions();
    manageListsPerms.initPropertiesFromJson(data.d.EffectiveBasePermissions);

    var manageLists = manageListsPerms.has(SP.PermissionKind.ApproveItems);

    var message = jQuery("#message");
    message.text("Approve ListItem: " + manageLists);
});
```

}